# Bloquear acceso por IP directa a mi servidor Apache 2

Tags: apache2

Hola tengo 2 dudas principales sobre la configuración de Apache 2 en Debian 11.

La primera se trata de cómo bloquear el ingreso al servidor Web mediante la IP directa y que en su lugar me diga **403 Forbidden**. Solamente debería dejar ingresar desde el dominio y no desde la dirección IP.

Mi segunda duda, básicamente, era como poder modificar el mensaje de error de **403 Forbidden** para ponerlo más elegante.

Ésta es la configuración del sitio por defecto:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName changenow.facusalgado.com
    ServerAlias changenow.facusalgado.com
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Tan sencillo como configurarlo en el dominio virtual por defecto y tu página accedida a través de nombre de dominio configuarla como lo tenías anteriormente. ¿Puedes compartir tu configuración para ayudarte a configurarlo correctamente?

Comment: PD: Deberías plantear una única duda por pregunta. En caso contrario tu pregunta podría cerrarse por ser demasiado amplia.

Comment: Bueno lo lamento.. aca tengo la configuracion

Comment: En lugar de `*` pon el nombre del dominio.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer uso de un sitio web por defecto que capture las conexiones directas a la IP tienes dos soluciones:

- Usar la configuración por defecto como receptáculo de todas las peticiones que no vayan a los sitios web configurados.

  - Ventajas: Si la IP de tu servidor cambia, agregas nuevas direcciones IP o quieres que también falle el acceso en caso de que intenten acceder a través de una URL que no has dado de alta, es la solución más adecuada.
- Usar una configuración específica para el sitio web accedido a través de la dirección IP.

  - Ventajas: requiere conocer la/s dirección/es IP y mantenerla/s en caso de cambios.

Personalmente, la primera opción es la que recomiendo nada más instalar un servidor.

Ya que has usado el archivo de configuración por defecto (`000-default.conf`) te indicaré cómo crear el sitio web para capturar las peticiones directas a la IP.

Crea el archivo `/etc/apache2/sites-available/999-ip.conf` con el siguiente contenido:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # Aquí debes poner tu dirección IP
        ServerName <dirección IP>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Te recomiendo separar los archivos de registro
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ip.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ip.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Luego debes activar el nuevo sitio web y recargar la configuración del servidor Apache:

```
a2ensite 999-ip.conf
systemctl reload apache2
```

Por último, [para configurar una página de error personalizada](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/custom-error.html) puedes quitar el acceso al directorio configurado en `DocumentRoot` (por ejemplo, creando un nuevo directorio al que el usuario `www-data` no tenga acceso) o bien  debes agregar a dicho archivo de configuración una línea como la que muestro a continuación:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

Con lo que deberás crear el archivo `403.html` con el contenido que desees mostrar.

Por último, para que todas las peticiones que lleguen sean respondidas con el código HTTP 403 puedes quitar el acceso al directorio configurado en `DocumentRoot` (por ejemplo, creando un nuevo directorio en el que el usuario `www-data` no tenga acceso) o bien agregar estas líneas a tu configuración:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
```

La regla coincidirá con cualquier URL (`.`), donde `R=403` es que devuelva un código HTTP 403 y `L` se usa para que sea la última regla de reescritura que se ejecute.

Recuerda que debe estar activado el módulo [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Si no lo tienes activado puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
a2enmod rewrite
systemctl restart apache2
```